# Why does running a program in bash work, when running it in the Menu doesn't?

Tags: linux, puppylinux

I presume there is something in the JWM window manager - or Puppy Linux Lupu 5.01 itself that is conflicting with the normal loading of GMPLAYER....

I would like to know how to troubleshoot, and fix this problem if possible (even a workaround would be great).

Answer (score 0):

Check the shortcut in the menu. I don't know how to do it in JVM, try right clicking on a menu item, then click "Properties". If it doesn't work, drag it to the desktop, and right click + Properties there (it definetely works on GNOME). In the worst case, open the .desktop file in a text editor.

Find a field named "Command" or something similar (it's "Exec" in the .desktop file). When you click on the menu item, it will execute that command. If it is the same that you try from terminal, try checking the "Run in terminal" check box (or set `Terminal=true` in the .desktop file). If not, change the command to the same that works for you. You may also check the working directory.

Comment: Yep, tried that already... unfortunately JWM doesn't support drag and drop... or right click for menu properties.... 
I believe the problem must be something wrong how JWM itself is setup.... cause the same menu item (.desktop file) works in fluxbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CTRL+ALT+Fx to switch to a text console with the log output from the X server (some distros work this way), you can look for an error message related to the problem. Also check /var/log/Xorg.0.log to see if anything appears there that might give you a hint about what's wrong.